# chart.js tooltip does not appear if zero value in data

Tags: javascript, charts

First, sorry for my poor english ;)

Maybe I forgot something, but sometimes, the tooltip does not appear when I put the mouse cursor on the legend label, and sometimes it appears. It seems to be function of the data values. Look at following Jsfiddle

The only difference between the two cases, is the values of the data.
As you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/neeqkowlhas/x5jrs3a9/2/), when i have a zero value in the data, if you put your mouse cursor over the "2016" label for exemple, the tooltip does not appear

**html**

```
<canvas id="graphCanvasYear" width="680" height="340" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; width: 680px; height: 340px;"></canvas>
```

**javascript**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("graphCanvasYear");
var chartdata = {
    datasets: [{
        borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
        hoverBorderColor: '#000000',
        borderAlign: 'inner',
        data: [10, 2, 4, 0, 5, 3],
    }],
    labels: ["2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"],
};
var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartdata,
    options: {
        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                bottom: 90
            }
        },
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        responsive: true,
        title: {
            position: 'bottom',
            display: true,
            text: 'Nb'
        }
    }
});
```

but [here](https://jsfiddle.net/neeqkowlhas/x5jrs3a9/1/), if I replace the zero value by eigth, the tooltip appears if you put the mouse cursor over the legend

**html**

```
<canvas id="graphCanvasYear" width="680" height="340" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; width: 680px; height: 340px;"></canvas>
```

**javascript**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("graphCanvasYear");
var chartdata = {
    datasets: [{
        borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
        hoverBorderColor: '#000000',
        borderAlign: 'inner',
        data: [10, 2, 4, 8, 5, 3],
    }],
    labels: ["2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"],
};
var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartdata,
    options: {
        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                bottom: 90
            }
        },
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        responsive: true,
        title: {
            position: 'bottom',
            display: true,
            text: 'Nb'
        }
    }
});
```

Is it a bug? Did I forget to set a property?

thank a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between your examples is that the first one starts at `0` and the other starts at `2`. I'm guessing that by default it doesn't show the tooltip for `0` values.

I tried changing some of the settings and found that adding the below had a similar behaviour to what you're looking for.

```
tooltips: {
    intersect: false
}
```

[Tooltip · Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html)

[image: Tooltip Chart.js intersect documentation]

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("graphCanvasYear");
var chartdata = {
  datasets: [{
    borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
    hoverBorderColor: '#000000',
    borderAlign: 'inner',
    data: [10, 2, 4, 0, 5, 3],
  }],
  labels: ["2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"],
};


var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: chartdata,
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 90
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      position: 'bottom',
      display: true,
      text: 'Nb'
    },
    tooltips: {
      intersect: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="graphCanvasYear" width="680" height="340" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; width: 680px; height: 340px;"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```